# PHP Multi-Dimensional Arrays Issue

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, data-retrieval

Ok I have a mult-dimensional array which has the following structure...

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'membership' => 
    array (
      'member' => 
      array (
        'name' => '',
        'landline' => '',
        'libcard' => '',
        'mobile' => '',
        'email' => '',
      ),
      'updated_at' => '',
      'member_id' => 12345,
      'starts_at' => '',
      'id' => 14,
      'group_id' => 280,
      'optional_field_values' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'optional_field' => 
          array (
            'name' => '',
            'updated_at' => '',
            'id' => 1,
            'group_id' => 280,
            'description' => '',
            'created_at' => '',
          ),
          'updated_at' => '',
          'optional_field_id' => 1,
          'membership_id' => 14,
          'id' => 4,
          'value' => '12539267',
          'created_at' => '',
        ),
      ),
      'ends_at' => '',
      'joining_fee' => 0,
      'created_at' => '',
    ),
   ),
```

Now I can access everything inside Membership and inside Member using code like...

```
$member[0]['membership']['member']['name']
or 
$member[0]['membership']['joining_fee']
```

But when ever I try to access stuff inside optional_field_values I get nothing returned...

Any ideas why this is not working?

Edit:

Trying to access the field using code like...

```
$member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values']['value']
```

Comment: Code sample for the part where you actually do the access? :)

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using to access the field.

Comment: And how are you trying to access that field? Maybe you're forgetting about the '0' there?

Comment: You should look more carefully what you are doing, this is a easy bug to catch. Ok php should warn you that `$member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values']['value']`
 is not allowed, but you can't help you have to deal with it.

Comment: @mathk No you will find it doesn't give you a warning or any message what's so ever...

Comment: @Aran I know that it does not, that is why you should deal with it. Or use a less  stupid language. Btw you can try to configure PHP so that it give you more error message see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: You could also print_r($member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values']) to see which index to use next ... btw, if the array contains NULL-Values, var_dump will show them more clearly than print_r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values'][0]['value']
```

^ Should work...

(Edited to match OP's edit)

Comment: ZING! That works now, didn't realise I would need a [0] in it.

Comment: @Aran - check my edit, now I know what value you're after. (You'd missed out the `[0]`)

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```
$member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values'][0]['value']
```

You can iterate over all optional field values like this :

```
foreach ($member[0]['membership']['optional_field_values'] as $field)
   echo $field['value'];
```